# Task with 3 methods

Tags: java

Have problem with my task I need to create a Person class with : name, city, age. And 3 methods:

1. A method that will return the oldest person from the given array argument
2. A method that will return how many people are from a given city (the method is supposed to get a table of people and the name of the city we count as arg)
3. Method that will calculate the average age of people from the city given as an argument (and of course an array of people)

Im wrong with the code and please for help to how to solve this task

```
private class Person {
String name;
String city;
int age;

}

private Person enterPerson(Scanner sc) {
Person person = null;
String name = sc.next();
if(name != "done) {
    int age = sc.nextInt();
    person = new Person();
    person.name = name;
    person.age = age;
    person.city = city;
} 
return person;
}

private Person youngest(List<Person> list) {
Person youngest = null;
for(Person person: list) {
    if(youngest == null || youngest.age > person.age) {
         youngest = person;
    }
}
return person;
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is in the line `if(name != "done) {`. 1. You forgot a `"` behind `"done`. 2. Compare Strings like this: `name.equalsIgnoreCase("done")`. The other one works only in special cases

Comment: Another problem might be you have oldest named youngest and also you are missing the 2 other methods you are talking about..

Comment: Guys can you help to write methods? should I have  a PersonCollection class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have list of Persons, you may use Java Stream API to implement your methods, providing that class Person contains appropriate getter methods: `getAge`:

**1. Find person with minimal age:**
Stream has method [`min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-), using comparator by custom field via method reference `Person::getAge`

```java
public static Person youngest(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
                  .min(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))
                  .orElse(null);  
                  // or throw an exception .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new)
}
```

**2. Count people from the same city:**
Method [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) uses a predicate to select elements from the stream, and method [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) returns the number of the filtered elements.

```java
public static long countPeopleFromPlace(List<Person> persons, String city) {
    return persons.stream()
                  .filter(p -> city.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCity()))
                  .count();
}
```

**3. Get average age for people from the same city:**
In addition to method `filter`, an averaging collector [`Collectors.averagingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) is used for appropriate field, using the same method reference as above.

```java
public static double averageAgePeopleFromPlace(List<Person> persons, String city) {
    return persons.stream()
                  .filter(p -> city.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCity()))
                  .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Person::getAge));
}

// or using [`IntStream::average()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--) 
public static double averageAgePeopleFromCity2(List<Person> persons, String city) {
    return persons.stream()
                  .filter(p -> city.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getCity()))
                  .mapToInt(Person::getAge) // converted to IntStream
                  .average()  // OptionalDouble returned here
                  .orElse(0.0);
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/sTQRUj)

Comment: thanks a lot! where to write this method?

Comment: You can make a utility class with these methods.  Btw, why did you make your `Person` class `private`, is it used as a nested class in some `Main` class only?  You should consider making `Person` at least a `private static` then.

Comment: Be honest with Im confuse with this task and making a lot of stupid mistakes :(. Can you show me and write for me this class with this method??

Comment: Mistakes are not a big deal.  The more you make them, the more satisfaction you may get in the end.

Comment: @Johny98, I updated the answer, you may check the link to [demo](https://ideone.com/sTQRUj).  Please also read the article [What should I do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Appreciate and thanks for your help. a lot of work ahead of me.  Can U give some advise what to do to improve java skills? Im start learning a month ago and I know there a lot to improve

Comment: Can you please upvote and accept my answer?  Thank you.  As for improving the Java skills I can tell only that you should not be afraid of mistakes and keep trying by _yourself_  And if you're just a starter it's worth to work through a decent book or at least Oracle's tutorials.